# Are these ASCII / Unicode strings equivalent?

Tags: string, unicode, ascii

Is a "1055912799" ASCII string equivalent to "1055912799" Unicode string?

Comment: If you mean UTF-8, yes, they will be byte for byte comparable.  If you mean UTF-16, then they won't be byte for byte comparable, but there should be string comparison that calls them the same depending on what language you use.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You can't just say "Unicode string"; you have to say how your string is *encoded*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the digit characters 0 to 9 in Unicode are defined to be the same characters as in Ascii. More generally, all printable Ascii characters are coded in Unicode, too (and with the same code numbers, by the way).

Whether the internal representations as sequences of bytes are the same depends on the character encoding. The UTF-8 encoding for Unicode has been designed so that Ascii characters have the same coded representation as bytes as in the only encoding currently used for Ascii (which maps each Ascii code number to an 8-bit byte, with the first bit set to zero).

UTF-16 encoded representation for characters in the Ascii range could be said to be “equivalent” to the Ascii encoding in the sense that there is a simple mapping: in UTF-16, each Ascii characters appears as two bytes, one zero byte and one byte containing the Ascii number. (The order of these bytes depends on endianness of UTF-16.) But such an “equivalence” concept is normally not used and would not be particularly useful.

Comment: I guess to elaborate on my question...I have two functions, one that converts a decimal to an Ascii string and one that converts a decimal to a Unicode string (i assume UTF-16). 

Using the decimal to ascii converter, I get an output of "1055912799". Would I get the same output using the decimal to unicode converter?

Comment: I can’t guess what you mean by “converts a decimal”, but surely conversion to Ascii does not produce the same byte sequence as conversion to UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

Because ASCII is a subset of unicode, any ASCII string will be the same in unicode, assuming of course you encode it with UTF-8. Clearly a UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoding will cause it to be fairly bloated.

Comment: Not quite. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 all right, but not of other Unicode encodings _per se_ (UTF-16 et altri, since extra 0x00 are inserted).

Comment: @dda that would be why it says "assuming of course you encode it with UTF-8".